# Adjust lambda syntax to match required signature

Tags: lambda, arduino, static, esp32, arduino-c++

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73813900/use-lambda-function-as-microcontroller-interrupts-handler) question, but the answer seems does not fulfill my requirements.
The answer suggests to use `static` functions, instead I need to access the class members.

My (not-working) ideal code would be:

in myclass.h:

```
private:
    int foo = 0;

    hw_timer_t *_timer1s;
    void Setup();
```

in myclass.cpp:

```
void MyClass::Setup()
{
    _timer1s = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
    timerAttachInterrupt(_timer1s, [this]()
    {
        foo++;
    }, true);
}
```

of course I get the known conversion error:

> no suitable conversion function from "lambda ->void" to "void (*)()" exists

I understood the explanation from the linked question, but I don't understand how to change the proposed code in order to capture/access the class members (i.e. `foo`). Using `static` functions does not allow me to do this.

What is the right syntax here?

### UPDATE

As requested I add the whole class code:

myclass.h

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include <Arduino.h>
#include <RTClib.h>

class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();

private:
    int foo = 0;

    hw_timer_t *_timer1s;
    void Setup();
};

#endif // MYCLASS_H
```

myclass.cpp:

```
#include "myclass.h"

MyClass::MyClass()
{
    Setup();
}

void MyClass::Setup()
{
    _timer1s = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
    timerAttachInterrupt(_timer1s, [this]()
    {
        foo++;
    }, true);
    timerAlarmWrite(_timer1s, 1000000, true);
    timerAlarmEnable(_timer1s);
}
```

Here the compile output errors:

```
src/myclass.cpp: In member function 'void MyClass::Setup()':
src/myclass.cpp:40:12: error: cannot convert 'MyClass::Setup()::<lambda(void*)>' to 'void (*)()'
     }, true);

In file included from /home/mark/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/esp32-hal.h:92,
                 from /home/mark/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:36,
                 from include/myclass.h:4,
                 from src/myclass.cpp:1:
/home/mark/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-timer.h:40:53: note:   initializing argument 2 of 'void timerAttachInterrupt(hw_timer_t*, void (*)(), bool)'
 void timerAttachInterrupt(hw_timer_t *timer, void (*fn)(void), bool edge);
```

while the inline assistant of Visual Studio Code reports:

> no suitable conversion function from "lambda ->void" to "void (*)()" exists

Comment: its not about syntax, but a `void(*)()` is a bare function pointer, it carries no data or state where you could capture something

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai hence the answer is "you cannot access any member object from that interrupt handler"? Even if I don't use lambda but an explicit ISR function?

Comment: please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. You posted only fragments and then say "of course I get the known conversion error:" but thats not the case. When you try to compile the posted code there will be many other errors, but none about a conversion from lambda to `void(*)()`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai I will update the question, but I assure you this is the only error I get.

Answer (score 1):

A capturing lambda will not match `void(*)()` that you need to supply to `timerAttachInterrupt`. The solution is to use [`timerAttachInterruptArg`](https://espressif-docs.readthedocs-hosted.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/timer.html#timerattachinterruptarg) instead and supply `this` as argument.

> `void timerAttachInterruptArg(hw_timer_t * timer, void (*userFunc)(void*), void * arg);`
>
> - `timer` - timer struct.
> - `userFunc` - funtion to be called when interrupt is triggered.
> - `arg` - pointer to the interrupt arguments.

```cpp
void MyClass::Setup()
{
    _timer1s = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
    timerAttachInterruptArg(_timer1s, [](void* instance)
    {
        // cast `instance` back to a `MyClass*`:
        auto This = static_cast<MyClass*>(instance);
        This->foo++;
    }, this);
//     ^^^^   this becomes `void* instance` in the lambda

    //...
}
```

Of course, this won't work if `foo` is private. You could call a public member function instead to solve that.

Example:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:

    void timer_event() {
        // called by the lambda on the correct instance
        foo++;
    }

    void Setup() {
        _timer1s = timerBegin(0, 80, true);
        timerAttachInterruptArg(_timer1s, [](void* instance) {
            static_cast<MyClass*>(instance)->timer_event();
        }, this);

        // ...
    }

};
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm digging out why it cannot find `timerAttachInterruptArg`. I'm on ESP32 platform and it should be there.

Comment: @Mark You're welcome! I updated the answer with a link to the documentation I read.

Comment: @Mark If you don't have it, perhaps you have an old version of the library? [`cores/esp32/esp32-hal-timer.h`](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/cores/esp32/esp32-hal-timer.h) seems to support what I'm suggesting - but it does _not_ support `timerAttachInterrupt` with a `bool` for edge-triggering.

Comment: @Mark What I'm suggesting is only available in the new 3.0 API https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/releases/tag/3.0.0-alpha2 - It's in alpha state but if you want to try it out, you need to install the 3.0.0-alpha2 release (archives are listed in the link).